# Run django in https://example.org/directory - python and php

Tags: python, django, apache2, virtualhost, django-wsgi

I have a website https://example.org (HTTPS) with php, Apache2 . I need to run on the same server (Centos 6) a Django app.

It is possible execute django app in  https://example.org/my_django_app/?

I can execute in a subdomain (http://my_django_app.example.org/), The problem here is that I need to buy another certificate for the subdomain.

**Answer**

In Virtualhost configuration (Apache 2.2 ), change the normal configuration

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /my/route/wsgi.py
```

Specify the directory name.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /directory /my/route/wsgi.py
```

Your Django project  run in https://example.org/directory and your https://example.org execute php

Comment: What version of apache are you using? Just use an alias as they do here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @LiamSorsby My Apache2 version is 2.2.31

Comment: Have you tried using an alias in your apache conf?

Comment: Specify the directory name in WSGIScriptAlias. Thanks @LiamSorsby

Comment: No problem.  Add this as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted rather than in your question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit virtualhost configuration, and add the configuration for python

```
WSGIDaemonProcess inti python-path=/path/to/myproject:/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup inti
WSGIScriptAlias /directory /path/to/wsgi.py
```